# sql query select same column from 2 rows into 1 column

Tags: sql

I got problem like in example

```
RowNumber     id    name
------------------------------
1              1     txt1
---------------------------
2              1     txt2
----------
3              2     txt3 
----------
4              2     txt4
----------
5              2     txt5
----------
```

so i need query that gives me result like

```
RowNumber   ResultColumn
----------
1            (txt1 - txt2)
----------
2            (txt3 - txt4 - txt5)
----------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**MYSQL**

```
SELECT id,Group_Concat(name SEPARATOR " - ")
From Table1
Group By id
```

Use **[Group_Concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)**

**[Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82e22/2)**

**MSSQL**

```
SELECT id,
      name = STUFF((
          SELECT '- ' + convert(varchar(10),T2.name)
          FROM Table1 T2
          WHERE T1.id = T2.id
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM Table1 T1
GROUP BY id
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/577a1/1)**

Answer (score 2):

For Postgres you can use `string_agg()`

```
select id, 
       string_agg(name, ' - ' order by name)
from the_table
group by id
order by id
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL, you can use the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) function:

```
SELECT RowNumber, GROUP_CONCAT(name)
FROM T
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

**For SQL Server:**

```
SELECT id,
      name = STUFF((
          SELECT '-' + convert(varchar(10),T2.name)
          FROM TableName T2
          WHERE T1.id = T2.id
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM TableName T1
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id,name
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Example**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c22cda/5)</kbd>

**For MySQL:**

```
SELECT id,GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ' - ') as name
FROM TableName
GROUP BY id
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Example**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb2b7f/5)</kbd>

Result:

```
ID  NAME
1   txt1 - txt2
2   txt3 - txt4 - txt5
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's MySQL:

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR " - " ORDER BY name) AS Result
FROM myTable
GROUP BY id;
```